# How to pass value of each row table in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have page where it displays a list of orders. I'm trying pass the value of each row of the table when a user clicks on a button, but it always passes a null value to my controller & database.
Can anyone please help me or point me in to the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

The view,

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="product-title">
                <a href="/Main/Produktdetaljer/@item.ProductId?proid=@item.ProductId">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" class="item_name" value="@item.ProductName">
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="base-price price-box"> 
                        <span class="price"> 
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price) 
                            <input type="hidden"  class="price" value="@item.Price">
                        </span> 
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td class="QuantityOfProduct@(item.ProductId)">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
            <input type="hidden" class="quantity" value="@item.Quantity" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div><a class="sendordre" >Send</a></div>
</div>
```

The javascript,

```
$(".sendordre").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('tr').each(function (i, el) {
        var ProductName = $(el).children('td').children('.item_name').val();
        var Qty = $(el).children('td').children('.quantity').val();
        var Price = $(el).children('td').children('.price').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("SendOrdre", "Cart")",
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{ 
                   ProductName: ProductName,
                   Price: Price,
                   Qty: Qty,
                   send:"send"
            },
            success: function (run) {
                if (run) {
                    console.log("Ok");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("ERror");
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

The controller method,

```
public JsonResult SendOrdre(CustomerOrdersVM model) {

    DateTime CreatedAt = DateTime.Today;
    var SaveOrdrer = new CustomerOrders  {

        Qty = model.Qty
        ProductName = model.ProductName,
        Price = model.Price,
        CreatedAt = CreatedAt,
    };

    db.CustomerOrders.Add(SaveOrdrer);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: it would help a lot if you show the controller code

Comment: @ADyson just sec :)

Comment: @ADyson i just update my question with Controller :)

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry can we see the structure of CustomerOrdersVM as well please

Comment: And also... have you debugged the request in the client-side? i.e. have you watched the AJAX request in your browser's Network tool and checked that the request body contains the expected values for each of the variables?

Comment: BTW, a small way to make the code more efficient - `$(el).children('td').children` could be replaced by simply `$(el).find` . In fact this might be the issue you know....children() only goes one layer down in the DOM, but your item name and quantity fields are actually several layers down inside the tds...so probably it's simply not finding the values in the page.

Comment: @ADyson yes i debugged both server and client and both of them contains null value and also beeing save in database with null value

Comment: I added an answer below about what I think it is. Another side point though - if you're wanting to submit all the rows at once, it would be far more efficient to make the SendOrdre method accept a `List<CustomerOrdersVM>` and just use one AJAX request to send all the values together.

Comment: @ADyson yes, i change from children to find ,but still have same issue :(

Comment: I found another little problem. See my updated answer. I also provided a demo so you can see exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace

```
$(el).children('td').children
```

with simply

```
$(el).find
```

`.children()` only goes one layer down in the DOM, but your item name and quantity fields are actually several layers down inside the tds...so probably it's simply not finding the values in the page. `.find()` is more flexible and will keep on searching down until it hits the selector. So it's far less dependent on the precise structure of your HTML.

You also need to change `<span class="price">` to something else - this duplicates the "price" class of your hidden field, and confuses jQuery about which element you're trying to find. Since the span is first, it finds that first, but spans don't have a "value", so running `.val()` on it returns nothing.

Lastly it would be sensible to restrict the loop just to finding rows within the orders table, otherwise it may operate on rows in other tables in your page, which is not desirable. For that purpose I've added an `id="ordersTable"` attribute to the table, and then changed the selector from `$("tr")` to `$("#ordersTable tr")` so it selects rows only within the intended table.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/children/ and https://api.jquery.com/find/

Here's a static demo (I created two rows, and replaced the Razor code with dummy output, and the ajax request with a log of the data to be sent):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sendordre").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $("#ordersTable tr").each(function(i, el) {
      var ProductName = $(el).find('.item_name').val();
      var Qty = $(el).find('.quantity').val();
      var Price = $(el).find('.price').val();
      /*$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Action("
        SendOrdre ", "
        Cart ")",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          ProductName: ProductName,
          Price: Price,
          Qty: Qty,
          send: "send"
        },
        success: function(run) {

          if (run) {

            console.log("Ok");
          } else {
            console.log("ERror");
          }
        },
      });*/
      //dummy test code
      console.log({
          ProductName: ProductName,
          Price: Price,
          Qty: Qty,
          send: "send"
        });
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="ordersTable" class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <a href="/Main/Produktdetaljer/1?proid=1">
                            Product1
                            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" class="item_name" value="Product1">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="base-price price-box"> <span class="priceSpan"> 100
                             <input type="hidden"  class="price" value="100"></span> </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </td>
                <td class="QuantityOfProduct1">

                    10
                    <input type="hidden" class="quantity" value="10" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="product-title">
                        <a href="/Main/Produktdetaljer/2?proid=2">
                            Product2
                            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" class="item_name" value="Product2">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="base-price price-box"> <span class="priceSpan"> 200
                             <input type="hidden"  class="price" value="200"></span> </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </td>
                <td class="QuantityOfProduct2">

                    20
                    <input type="hidden" class="quantity" value="20" />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div> <a class="sendordre">Send</a> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate :) right now i just have one row in tabel , but when i look at my databsae it will insert 4 rows into database every each time i hit the button

Comment: If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted". Thanks. P.S. If you can I would still aim to change your design so it submits all the rows in a single AJAX request. Once you have more than a couple of rows it will start to seem slow if you do multiple separate requests.

Comment: I can't see how it can be inserting 4 rows, unless there is some other problem in your code which you didn't show us. Look at what I demo'd - for 2 rows it outputs two console logs. That is equivalent to two AJAX requests (since I just swapped the AJAX call for the console call). It cannot do any more than that, it's impossible with the code as shown. Check your network tool and see how many ajax calls are actually being run when you test it.

Comment: Yes , your anwser is helped and i will mark it :) the only value i get its jut product name and i also check network it will posting 5 times :) i just dont get it why, any way thank for help :)

Comment: The only way it could post 5 times is if there are 5 table rows in your page. There must be some other difference between your version and mine, I guess. You will have to try and look very carefully for exactly what it is. Good luck. Maybe ask another question if you still have trouble.

Comment: One thing I wonder - is there any other table in the same page? Because `$("tr")` will select all table rows in the page, not just in the table you've shown above. That could be a sensible reason why a) it posts more times than you expect and b) it posts null values in some cases (because those fields don't exist in the other table).

Comment: hmm , get interesting ,you right .. beacuse i have two Partial view  One More Cart and anonther for Checkout  which almost both of them contains same value, but they are different in design  ,and i think its beacuse of dat its posting 5 times!!!

Comment: That makes sense then. I've updated the answer to include a fix to prevent that.

Comment: almost there mate :) now it will post 2 times ,one with totally null value and another with value , is there anyway can stop dat has not contains any value !

Comment: I can't imagine what's causing that - my demo doesn't do it, if you notice. Perhaps your Razor logic is printing a row with some blank values or something (e.g. maybe one of the items in Model doesn't contain any data) - check your actual HTML output using the brower View Source or HTML Inspector tools.

Comment: Thank you so much mate for time and help , i will look closer :)

Comment: Oh actually I wonder, does your table have a header row in reality? That could be it. If so try changing the selector again to "#ordersTable tbody tr" to get only the body rows

Answer (score -2):

Change `val()` to `text()`:

```
var ProductName = $(el).children('td').children('.item_name').text();
var Qty = $(el).children('td').children('.quantity').text();
var Price = $(el).children('td').children('.price').text();
```

Comment: text() works for price (because of the span) but not the others. And you didn't fix the traversal issue with .children(). It's sensible to actually test your code before posting. The code snippet feature makes that really easy with Javascript questions. Plus you didn't even explain _why_ anyone should apply your change.

Comment: mission accomplished!

Comment: you're getting played dude! it's all about intentions!

Comment: played by who? About what? Intentions to do what? You appear to be talking in riddles.....are you high...?

Comment: you're entertaining us on this slow friday morning!